# What's the next number in the following number sequence?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

The sequence is:

138, 29, 1, 382, 913, 8, X

Possible answers:

a) 9

b) 2

c) 3

d) 12

Note: This question is not mine and it was asked as an IQ question by a teacher.

Comment: Hi Areta and welcome to Puzzling :) Is this your own original puzzle or did you find it somewhere else? If elsewhere, please mention where you found it so the original content creator gets credit. Thanks :) ALSO: If this is from elsewhere, are there multiple-choice options provided? As I can see more than one possible solution for this...

Comment: Thanks for modifying your question, Areta. Hopefully my answer below helps you understand. If your teacher asks you more questions of this type, trying techniques like this might help you spot patterns. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the 4 possible answers, the correct one is:

> **b) 2**

Why?

> The previous terms (138, 29, 1, 382, 913, 8) comprise numbers made of the repeating sequence of digits (13829)(13829)(138...)
>
>  To continue this sequence you need to seek an answer beginning with 2 (or 29, or 291, etc.).
>
>  The only option which satisfies this is b), which is actually just 2 itself!